# CheckBox adding Parameter to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I have a `CheckBoxList` that is showing all **A** table **C** column.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT C
FROM A
ORDER BY C
```

My **A** table has two columns.

**B**-->Primary Key

**C**--> Every **C** has a unique **B**.

I have an **SQL** like this for my **Gridview** Source;

```
Select <...............>
From <..................>
Where <.................>
AND A.B IN 
(Select A.B 
From A 
Where A.C IN ALL CheckBoxList.SelectedItem.Value)
```

Something like that. My **SQL** syntax isn't very good. I hope you can tell what I want..

What I **REALLY** want is, when I click a button, **Gridview** should be populated according to the **SQL** , **BUT** filtered by what is selected in CheckBoxList.

Is there any way to add a parameter in the **SQL** IN clause?
How can I do that?

**Best Regards,**

**Soner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I encountered an issue like this, I took a data table (precomputed, equivalent to all the boxes being checked) and just used a LINQ query (I asked about that query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236866/linq-boilerplate-is-all-of-it-needed)).  Basically, in the context of your question, I just used a standard LINQ query, building a filter by ORing all the checkboxes to form a filter.  I created the filter itself using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).  I only needed the 26 lines of code under "Predicate Builder Source Code."

Answer (score 1):

Different Solution is discussed in the following URL : [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)
Have a look at it.